# Parsing Podcast XML with VB.NET: issue with itune tags

Tags: xml, vb.net, rss, itunes

I tried to parse this xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="/podcastics/podcasts/rss-rendering/rss.xsl"?>
<rss xmlns:atom="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" xmlns:content="http://purl.org/rss/1.0/modules/content/" xmlns:googleplay="http://www.google.com/schemas/play-podcasts/1.0" xmlns:itunes="http://www.itunes.com/dtds/podcast-1.0.dtd" xmlns:zippycast="https://zippycast.io" version="2.0">
  <channel>
    <generator>Podcastics</generator>
    <lastBuildDate>Sat, 06 Feb 2021 19:31:04 +0000</lastBuildDate>
    <zippycast:prefix>93ed347537474b068430866e6dfb57ea</zippycast:prefix>
    <title>Les Minutes de l'Horreur</title>
    <language>fr</language>
    <atom:link rel="hub" href="https://pubsubhubbub.appspot.com/" />
    <link>https://www.podcastics.com/podcast/les-minutes-de-lhorreur/</link>
    <itunes:type>episodic</itunes:type>
    <itunes:author>Lucas Fois</itunes:author>
```

Here's my code:

```
Dim doc As New XmlDocument()
doc.Load(podcast_rss_url)
Dim root As XmlElement = doc.DocumentElement

Dim nodes_1 As String = root.SelectSingleNode("channel/title").InnerText
Dim nodes_2 As String = root.SelectSingleNode("channel/language").InnerText
Dim nodes_3 As String = root.SelectSingleNode("channel/itunes:author").InnerText
```

My issue is with the last line (Dim nodes_3...): it returns nothing.

Comment: What bolded line?  Incomplete XML makes it hard to test...

Comment: Sorry, bold format is not effective in code. I edited.